# terraform data archive file source directory with selected files and directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create a data archive_file with selected files and folders as source_dir.
I have the folder structure as below. Within the src directory, I have lambdas directory and within that there are few folders
and a set of files as below.

```
src
|-lambdasfolder
  |-__init__.py
  |-commonfolder (config.py, __init__.py)
  |-lambda1folder (requesthandler.py, __init__.py)
  |-lambda2folder (requesthandler.py, __init__.py)
  |testsfolder
  |otherfolder
  ...
```

I want to create a source directory for data archive file with selected folders and files. I want a create a src directory with just a single file and couple of directories matching the
structure below.

```
src
|-lambdasfolder
  |-__init__.py
  |-commonfolder (config.py, __init__.py)
  |-lambda1folder (requesthandler.py, __init__.py)
```

I am finding the examples as below which zips the entire directory, but how can I zip only the required ones

```
data "archive_file" "lambda_source"{
  type = "zip"

  source_dir  = "${path.module}/../src"
  output_path = "${path.module}/temp/src.zip"
}
```

I have managed to get working to some extent by creating a null reference and archive file dependant on it.

```
resource "null_resource" "lambda-repo" {  
    triggers = {
     #not sure on this
   }

 provisioner "local-exec" {  
    command = "bash lambda-repo.sh"
    working_dir = "${path.module}"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "lambda-repo-file" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.lambda-repo]
  type = "zip"

  source_dir  = "${path.module}/lambda_archive/lambda-repo"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda_archive/lambda-repo.zip"

}
```

and the shell script as follows

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p lambda_archive/lambda-repo/lambdasfolder/common
mkdir -p lambda_archive/lambda-repo/lambdasfolder/lambda1folder
touch lambda_archive/lambda-repo/lambdasfolder/__init__.py
cp -r ../src/lambdasfolder/common/. lambda_archive/lambda-repo/lambdasfolder/common
cp -r ../src/lambdasfolder/lambda1folder/. lambda_archive/lambda-repo/lambdasfolder/lambda1folder
```

And also on the s3 object, I need to comment the etag for the initial terraform apply

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "lambda-repo" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda-repo.id

  key    = "lambda-repo.zip"
  source = data.archive_file.lambda-repo-file.output_path
  #had to comment etag 
  #etag = filemd5(data.archive_file.lambda-repo-file.output_path)
}
```

Now I am left with two issues.

1. It is not detecting any changes in lambda functions when terraform apply is executed after the first run
2. How do I remove the folders and zip folders created through null resource?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Bit unsure on this. I will try if I can create a temp folder, copy the required ones into it and zip it using local-exec. I don't know if I can able to fit in all the commands and also need to make sure these commands run first and be available for data archive file. Will see if I can find an example

Comment: I tried to implement the local-exec as updated in the post but left with two issues. Any changes in lambda function are not detected when terraform apply is executed after the first run and how do I clean the resources created as part of local-exec shell script after provisioning the resources. Appreciate your help

Comment: created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71759028/terraform-local-exec-not-detecting-the-lambda-source-code-changes 

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't do this, unless you want to use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) to  create the zips in a fully custom way. Otherwise, you have to re-organize your folder structure to have fully separate folders for  `archive_file`.