# local-exec not detecting the lambda source code changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created a null resource with local-exec provisioner which runs a shell script to get required folders for lambda source code to zip.

```
resource "null_resource" "lambda-repo" {  
    triggers = {
     #not sure on this
   }

 provisioner "local-exec" {  
    command = "bash lambda-repo.sh"
    working_dir = "${path.module}"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "lambda-repo-file" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.lambda-repo]
  type = "zip"

  source_dir  = "${path.module}/lambda_archive/lambda-repo"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda_archive/lambda-repo.zip"

}
```

and the shell script as follows

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p lambda_archive/lambda-repo/lambdasfolder/common
mkdir -p lambda_archive/lambda-repo/lambdasfolder/oob_check_challenge
touch lambda_archive/lambda-repo/lambdasfolder/__init__.py
cp -r ../src/lambdasfolder/common/. lambda_archive/lambda-repo/lambdasfolder/common
cp -r ../src/lambdasfolder/lambda1folder/. lambda_archive/lambda-repo/lambdasfolder/lambda1folder
```

To get this working for the initial terraform apply, I need to comment the etag in the s3 object.

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "lambda-repo" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda-repo.id

  key    = "lambda-repo.zip"
  source = data.archive_file.lambda-repo-file.output_path
  #had to comment etag 
  #etag = filemd5(data.archive_file.lambda-repo-file.output_path)
}
```

For the first terraform apply, the above terraform script worked fine by uploading the required source code to lambda.

Now the issue is,It is not detecting any changes in lambda function when terraform apply is executed after the first run.How to write a Trigger in null_resource to detect any file changes within a directory?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: I feel like having an additional stage in the pipeline which does all the scripting and get it ready prior to preparation of terraform environment would be better rather than trying to achieve everything through terraform which probably may not be the right approach in my case

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **always** execute your `local-exec` for each `apply`, you can do the following:

```
resource "null_resource" "lambda-repo" {  
    triggers = {
     always_run = timestamp()
   }

 provisioner "local-exec" {  
    command = "bash lambda-repo.sh"
    working_dir = "${path.module}"
  }
}
```

But if you want to run `local-exec` after a **new version** of `lambda_handler.py` has been created, you can do (`lambda_handler.py` is example name):

```
resource "null_resource" "lambda-repo" {  
  triggers = {
    always_run = md5(file("../src/lambdasfolder/common/lambda_handler.py"))
  }

 provisioner "local-exec" {  
    command = "bash lambda-repo.sh"
    working_dir = "${path.module}"
  }
}
```

`lambda_handler.py` should be replaced by the name of your actual handler file. Thus when its content changes, `md5` will be different, thus triggering the `local-exec`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can we apply md5 to detect any file change within a directory rather than a single handler file

Comment: @ChinnaR I'm not aware of a method which you could do that. Maybe using custom data source instead of md5 would allow you to achieve that.

Comment: For Terraform 1.4 we can use `terraform_data` and `triggers_replace` in place of `null_resource`

Comment: I think we can have something like `for file in fileset(pattern) : filemd5(file)` for `triggers_replace` because it takes multiple values. I hope it answers your question @ChinnaR